# Error serializing DataStore data with arrays of custom types:com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:Not a JSON Object:[]

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify, datastore

I have an error when I add a table with a custom type. Whenever I try to create an Info by filling in the comment and asset fields, whether it's an empty array ([]) or an array of values, it gives me an error
Everything works fine with DataStore when comments and assets are defined as [String] or [AWSJSON] but I still have [Comment] and [Asset] to keep validations in my data

> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): Error ended observation of mutation outbox:
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: []
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:975)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1034)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter$GsonContextImpl.deserialize(TreeTypeAdapter.java:162)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.amplifyframework.datastore.appsync.SerializedModelAdapter.deserialize(SerializedModelAdapter.java:115)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.amplifyframework.datastore.appsync.SerializedModelAdapter.deserialize(SerializedModelAdapter.java:43)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:69)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:963)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:928)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:877)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.amplifyframework.datastore.syncengine.GsonPendingMutationConverter.fromRecord(GsonPendingMutationConverter.java:72)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.amplifyframework.datastore.syncengine.PersistentMutationOutbox.lambda$load$15$com-amplifyframework-datastore-syncengine-PersistentMutationOutbox(PersistentMutationOutbox.java:260)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.amplifyframework.datastore.syncengine.PersistentMutationOutbox$$ExternalSyntheticLambda16.accept(Unknown Source:6)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.amplifyframework.datastore.storage.sqlite.SQLiteStorageAdapter.lambda$query$4$com-amplifyframework-datastore-storage-sqlite-SQLiteStorageAdapter(SQLiteStorageAdapter.java:406)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.amplifyframework.datastore.storage.sqlite.SQLiteStorageAdapter$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:10)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: []
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonObject(JsonElement.java:91)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.amplifyframework.datastore.appsync.SerializedCustomTypeAdapter.deserialize(SerializedCustomTypeAdapter.java:80)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.amplifyframework.datastore.appsync.SerializedCustomTypeAdapter.deserialize(SerializedCustomTypeAdapter.java:41)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:69)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:963)
> E/amplify:aws-datastore(26048): ... 20 more

My code:

```
User user = await _globalFunction.getConnectedUser();
List assets = [];
var key;
List<Future> uploadTasks = [];

  // Upload image to Storage
  for (final imageFile in fileList!) {
    final size = await imageFile?.length();
    key =
        'info-images/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}';

    // Create a task for each upload operation and add it to the list
    final uploadTask = _globalFunction.uploadedFile(
      path: imageFile.path,
      file: File(imageFile.path),
      key: key,
      name: imageFile.name,
    );
    uploadTasks.add(uploadTask);

    final asset = Asset(
        id: uuid(),
        name: imageFile.name,
        number: 0,
        size: size?.toDouble(),
        path: key,
        content: imageFile.mimeType,
        contentType: ContentType.PICTURE);

    assets.add(asset);
  }

  // Wait for all the upload tasks to complete
  await Future.wait(uploadTasks);

  TemporalDateTime dateTime = TemporalDateTime(DateTime.now());

  // Create Info
  Info inf = Info(
    title: "title.text",
    user: user,
    comments: [],
    assets: assets,
  );
  await Amplify.DataStore.save(inf);
```

Mon schema de donnees

```
type User
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: public, operations: [create, read, update], provider: apiKey }
      { allow: private, operations: [create, read, update] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID! 
  ...
  infos: [Info] @hasMany(indexName: "byUser", fields: ["id"]) 
}

type Info
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: public, operations: [create, read, update], provider: apiKey }
      { allow: private, operations: [create, read, update] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID! 
  title: String! 
  type: InfoType! 
  assets: [Asset]
  rating: Int 
  likes: [String]
  comments: [Comment] 
  userID: ID! @index(name: "byUser", sortKeyFields: ["title"]) 
  user: User @belongsTo(fields: ["userID"]) 
}
type Comment {
  id: ID! # Identifiant du commentaire
  picture: String # Lien vers une image associée au commentaire
  comment: String # Contenu du commentaire
  rate: Float # Évaluation du commentaire
}

type Asset {
  id: ID! # Identifiant de la ressource
  ...
  contentType: ContentType # Type de contenu de la ressource
}
```